# Terminal doesn't read whole text file if too long

Tags: python, terminal

So I'm using a basic read() code in python, but the terminal can only print the last few lines and I can't scroll back up to the beginning. What if I want the terminal to print out the whole thing, without limiting how far back I can go?

Comment: Most terminal emulators allow you to specify the size of the terminal buffer. For performance reasons, the default is rarely to allow the buffer to grow without limit. How to change the size of the buffer, and whether an unbounded buffer is even allowed, depends on the specific terminal emulator you are using.

Comment: Many possibilities: increase the linebuffer of your terminal (or use a different one), or pipe your output into a tool like less, or make your python code wait for the user to press enter after reading a few lines.